# How to get full packageName of fuction parameter?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

[image]
I have class, that extends from baseActionHandler,
In generator I want to get the full packageName of T, but can get only name of T

```kotlin
classDeclaration.superTypes.first().element?.typeArguments?.first()?.type.toString()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classDeclaration.superTypes.first().element?.typeArguments?.first()?.type?.resolve()?.toClassName()

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer please add more details how you got to it.